# Как использовать Xdebug в UnitTest

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony2, xdebug

Имеется phpstorm, symfony, настроенный xDebug всё дебажится кроме unittest-ов

Comment: А в cli-окружении включен xdebug?

Comment: нет и не знаю как включить =) мне сказали что вообще нельзя использовать xdebug в phpunit test-ах

Comment: В каком смысле "нельзя"?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman в том что типа не возможно, говорил человек который вряд ли в этой теме понимает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё всем дебажится:

```
sudo php5enmod -s cli xdebug
```

Comment: А на windows как?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, к счастью не знаю. Разработка на Windows это боль.

Comment: к счастью на перевели на linux все теперь легко =)